# How to Debug .net applications without Visual Studio

Tags: .net, debugging, remote-debugging

Please let me know if this has been asked before, I wasn't able to find any questions on this subject:-

I need to determine the inner exception of an exception thrown on a computer with the .net framework installed but not Visual Studio (nor is it possible to install Visual Studio on the computer). How can I examine this inner exception?

Note a few points:

- It's no good running Visual Studio from another computer as the problem lies actually on the box; it's a heisenbug of the first order.
- I know WinDbg is an option, however I need this done quickly and unfortunately I imagine the time taken to learn WinDbg sufficiently to get this done will outweigh the time I have - however if anybody has step-by-step instructions on this I would be interested.
- I have full admin permissions and can install anything that isn't too big (the problem with installing VS is that there is insufficient hard drive space).

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Have you had a [look at MDBG](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/tools/mdbg-exe)? It may take you a while to get around but is fairly straight forward.

Also [DbgClr](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/archive/blogs/andypennell/does-anyone-use-dbgclr-or-even-know-what-it-is) may be an option, I think its still supposed to be in the SDK somewhere.

Answer (score 9):

It is actually fairly simple to do this with WinDbg if you have a crash dump. Load the dump into WinDbg, load sos, and run the printexception command.

```
>.load sos
>!printexception
```

This will tell you the exception as well as point you to the inner exception. Output will be something like:

```
0:000> !printexception
Exception object: 0135b340
Exception type: System.ApplicationException
Message: GetAverage failed
InnerException: System.IndexOutOfRangeException, use !PrintException 01358394 to see more
<stack trace follows>
```

If you don't have a memory dump already, you can create one using adplus (which comes with WinDbg).

```
>adplus -crash -o<dump location> -quiet -pn<name of process>
```

If you prefer to use PID use the `-p` option instead.

Comment: I really want to learn windbg so I'm sure I'll get onto this at some point; however for the moment mdbg did the job nicely.

Comment: No problem. WinDbg takes some getting used to, but once you get past that it is really powerful for certain types of problems.

Answer (score 2):

you can use remote debugging: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/y7f5zaaa.aspx

Comment: Turned out the exception was caught so I needed to catch a first-chance exception, which I wasn't able to get working using remote debugging.