# How can i debug a program written in c# without VS

Tags: c#, debugging

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to Debug .net applications without Visual Studio](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/819446/how-to-debug-net-applications-without-visual-studio)

Hi i made a small program it works for me and for a few people

but its being crashed at a friend

how can i debug and learn which lines exactly causes error?

```
without installing visual studio
```

Comment: you can check this out

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/819446/how-to-debug-net-applications-without-visual-studio

Comment: What are your constraints? Can you install another IDE? Can you install other software at all? Can you change the source code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Best you can do is (and is a good coding practice) in a new buid add try catch exception block in methods with logging facility that logs(in catch block) in lets say a text file

1. Method Name (Find using new StackTrace()..GetFrame(1).GetMethod().Name or `System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().Name`),
2. its parameters and
3. Exception message.

Comment: I would save the parameters and the exception.ToString() which has already the complete stack trace.

Answer (score 2):

If you don't mean "without installing a debugger" you could try using [Mono](http://mono-project.com/Main_Page).

Answer (score 1):

You can use WinDbg which can be run portable (xcopy from an existing installation), and with the SoS add-on it can help a lot in debugging C# applications - even in post mortem. It might be difficult to grasp at first, but it's worth learning - it will come very useful in several situations.

SoS reference here : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb190764.aspx

I have this quick cheat-sheet with what I found most useful (found somewhere on the internet and then enriched with time) :

```
Starting, Attaching, Executing and Exiting


Start -> All Programs -> Debugging Tools for Windows -> WinDbg
F6
attach to process
Ctrl-Break
interrupt debugee
.detach
detach from a process
g
continue debugee execution
q
exit WinDbg

Getting Help
?
help on commands that affect the debugee
.help
help on commands that affect the debugger
.hh command
view the on line help file
!help
help on the extension dll at the top of the chain (e. g., SOS)

Issuing Commands
up arrow, down arrow, enter
scroll through command history
Right mouse button
paste into command window

Examining the Unmanaged Environment
lmf
list loaded modules with full path
lmt
list loaded modules with last modified timestamp
~
list unmanaged threads
~thread s
select a thread for thread specific commands
!token -n
view thread permissions
k
view the unmanaged call stack
!runaway
view thread CPU consumption
bp
set a breakpoint
.dump path
dump small memory image
.dump /ma path
dump complete memory image

Working with Extension DLLs (e. g., SOS)
.chain
list extensions dlls
.load clr10\sos
load SOS for debugging framework 1.0 / 1.1 (use .unload to unload)
.loadby sos mscorwks
load SOS for debugging framework 2.0
.loadby sos clr
load SOS for debugging framework 4.0

SOS Commands
!threads
view managed threads
!clrstack
view the managed call stack
!dumpstack
view combined unmanaged & managed call stack
!clrstack -p
view function call arguments
!clrstack –l
view stack (local) variables
!name2ee module class
view addresses associated with a class or method
!dumpmt –md address
view the method table & methods for a class
!dumpmd address
view detailed information about a method
!do address
view information about an object
!dumpheap –stat
view memory consumption by type
!dumpheap –min size
view memory consumption by object when at least size
!dumpheap –type type
view memory consumption for all objects of type type
!gcroot address
view which object are holding a reference to address
!syncblk
view information about managed locks

SOS 2.0 Commands
!bpmd module method
set breakpoint
!DumpArray address
view contents of an array
!PrintException
view information about most recent exception
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want to install any other debugger,

Then you should simply implement trace and  log on each section of code carefully and then you can view the traces or errors on the text file..

Ways to implement trace and log:

use can use `TraceListener` class on `system.diaognosis` namespace 
or use

```
Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Logging namespace's class `Logger` to implement tracing:
```

syntax:

```
Logger.Write(message, "Trace", 0, 0, System.Diagnostics.TraceEventType.Information);
```